# How to change settings in a middleware?

Tags: python, django, apache

I'd like to change the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` (along with a few others) and then have ALL relevant modules like `django.conf`, `django.db` etc reloaded to reflect the information from the new settings module. The new settings module will have different database. I will be doing this in a middleware.
I was able to achieve this by reloading a few modules along with `django.conf` and `django.db`. All new SQL statements were fired against the new DB.
But this appears to be so hackish.

The main reason for me wanting to do this is to have the same apache child process serve requests for different django applications (different settings and not different apps) without having to recreate a new apache child process which reloads the whole thing.

Is there a clean way of achieving what I want to do?

Thanks,

**UPDATE (19-Sept-2014):** I have accepted Daniel Roseman's answer as that seems to be the reality in the context of the question asked. The Router approach suggested by him was something that I explored but couldn't use because django's transaction classes don't use the router. The router I presume exists for a different reason. The application code base I'm working on, which is pretty large, has tons of transaction.commit_manually for the default or a specific db alias. I was trying to get this to support multiple client databases without changing the application code.
However, I did manage to solve the main problem which was to support multiple client DBs and other settings. I don't try to change the settings on the fly nor do I use the router. I instead have a single settings.py with all client DB information. I monkey patched the connection handler to return a different database connection for 'default' alias (or other specific alias used by the code) based on certain env variables set in the middleware. So far this has worked fine. I will post an update if I run into any issues or if someone else can point out a potential issue with the approach.

Comment: No, there is no way to achieve what you want to do within a single python process. There could always be an object using a value from settings as a default ending up with stale configuration.

Comment: I am trying to do exactly this right now. How do you manage to set the default  db from the middleware? The approach I am trying basically is import `settings.DATABASES` into the middlewares file, get the subdomain name and try to change the db connection based in the subdomain from the `request.get_host()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this, and that's a very good thing as it is a bad idea. There is no reason to use the same Apache process for different sites: instead you should have different virtual hosts for each of your sites, and let Apache manage them.

Comment: Why do you say there is no good reason to use the same apache process? I now need to have multiple servers or virtual hosts for each site and there will be many idle processes because I have set MaxRequestsPerChild to a high number for performance reasons. That for me is not optimal. I'd like to be able to use those idle processes to process requests for other sites/clients. Especially because they use the same code but different DBs.

Comment: So, in order to increase performance you'd rather reload the code on every single request, thus breaking performance? Doesn't sound like a good idea. In any case, if the only difference is the db, you should use the [multiple db support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/multi-db/) to route your request to the right db.

Comment: Well, not reload ALL code, but I was hoping I can get through reload a few modules without affecting performance much. The multiple db thing is one option that I'm exploring. I'm assessing the impact because we assume the default db in most parts of the app. Not sure if DB routing will help in my case. It's not just DB settings but a few other attrs from django settings as well that can be client specific. Also seeing if I can tweak apache settings in some way minimise the number of idle processes but use pre forking and have multiple requests per process at the same time.